# Dropdown Yii 2.0 with 2 parameters

Tags: php, sql, yii, yii2, dropdownbox

I'm developing a dropdown list that gets the values and his related from the same table.

AssetType
asset_type_id
name
order
parent_asset_type (related to AssetType.asset_type_id) - the top type as value = NULL

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'asset_type_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(AssetType::find()->where("parent_asset_type IS NOT NULL")->all(), 'asset_type_id', 'name', 'parent_asset_type'),
                 ['prompt'=>'Choose a Category']);?>
```

And with this Yii2 arrayHelper i can save 3 values, the id of the asset which is not null, his name and the parent_asset_type (Which shows the ID)

Basically:

```
DropDownList
Choose a Category
1
  T-Shirts
  Jeans
2
  Computers
  Cellphones
```

Instead of the group Id i would love to know how can i make it show the name of that Asset Type.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you...

I have created a function in the model modelname.php

```
public function getAssetType(){
        return $this->name .'-'.$this->parent_asset_type;
    }
```

view.php

```
<?php

$asset = ArrayHelper::map(AssetType::find()->all(),'id','AssetType');
echo $form->field($model, 'asset_type_id')->dropDownList($asset,
                 ['prompt'=>'Choose a Category']);

?>
```

Thank You...